# User ID vs ID for primary key dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in which has a "userId" column (set as a partition key) and a "createdAt" column (set as the sort key) so they form up a composite primary key.

I also need to find the exact row in case I don't have the User ID available, so I made another column "id" and made it as a global secondary index.

In my case, should I make the "id" column the primary key and remove the "userId" as the partition key or will this remove the feature of what "Partitioning" actually does by the DynamoDB?

Similarly, If I need to delete a row from the table, should I send "createdAt" field from the front end to be able to find out the exact row? Does this make sense? Sending the "id" of the row seems more good to me to be able to delete the row.

Comment: OK, so generate a UUID or supply a unique ID, store it in an ID attribute with each item that is written and create a GSI for ID. You'll then be able to delete an item by querying the GSI for the related ID, retrieving the partition/sort keys and deleting the item. How your client/app knows which ID to delete is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to put a timestamp in your user primary keys.  Why?  You'd need to know the exact time the user was created to fetch a user, which is probably not what you want.

Consider using a partition key of `USER#<user_id>` and a sort key of something predictable, like `A` or `METADATA` or `USER#<user_id>`.  This allows you to fetch/delete a user by their ID.

If you have access patterns around fetching users in order of account creation, you can create a GSI with the sort key set to the `createdAt` attribute.

Comment: The timestamp isn't a part of a primary key to fetch the user details (not the USERS table). The user creates a "record" and that record contains "UserID" as partition key and "Timestamp" as the sort key. I'll also need to fetch the row using "ID" which is unique to every row (I'm making it as GSI)

Comment: Also, what do the `A` and `METADETA` correspond to?

Comment: It seems that I do not understand what you are asking. Can you clarify your access patterns?

Comment: Okay. I have a table in which the items will be stored created by the users (the users are stored in the Cognito.) Let's call this table as "cars"
Whenever a user creates a new car record, it will be saved in the "cars" table along with the "userId" (partition key) and "timestamp" (sort key)
Now, if I need to delete this row, I should be able to delete it by using the row ID (which should be apart from the user ID and timestamp) so I make GSI of a new column called ID but I believe this structure isn't correct. Admin can delete this record too so in that case, I won't have the user ID avail